# erro com managedObjectContext

Tags: swift

Adicionei um `CoreData` no meu projeto `Model.xcdatamodeld` e gostaria de saber por que quando eu faço a chamada do `managedObjectContext` diz que a classe não existe?

Segue a print para que entenda melhor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual erro o **xcode** está apontando na linha?

Comment: Boa dia Luis Henrique, o erro é

Value of type appDelegate has no member 'managedObjectContext'

Comment: talvez seja por que no comeco da aplicacao eu nao marquei que usaria um coredata, gostaria de saber se depois da aplicacao semipronta teria como colocar

Comment: É possível adicionar o CoreData mais tarde sim, no entanto você tem de adicionar o framework do CoreData, e criar os métodos necessários na classe AppDelegate (esse procecesso ele faz sozinho quando você cria um projeto do zero)

Comment: De uma olhada nesse artigo, ele deve lhe ajudar: http://craig24.com/2014/12/how-to-add-core-data-to-an-existing-swift-project-in-xcode/